# Why do I have to run two variables in the sess.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was doing the deep learning specialisation by Coursera ..and in that making a CNN using tensor flow

```
def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate = 0.009,
      num_epochs = 100, minibatch_size = 64, print_cost = True):
"""
Implements a three-layer ConvNet in Tensorflow:
CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> FLATTEN -> FULLYCONNECTED

Arguments:
X_train -- training set, of shape (None, 64, 64, 3)
Y_train -- test set, of shape (None, n_y = 6)
X_test -- training set, of shape (None, 64, 64, 3)
Y_test -- test set, of shape (None, n_y = 6)
learning_rate -- learning rate of the optimization
num_epochs -- number of epochs of the optimization loop
minibatch_size -- size of a minibatch
print_cost -- True to print the cost every 100 epochs

Returns:
train_accuracy -- real number, accuracy on the train set (X_train)
test_accuracy -- real number, testing accuracy on the test set (X_test)
parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
"""

ops.reset_default_graph()                         # to be able to rerun the model without overwriting tf variables
tf.set_random_seed(1)                             # to keep results consistent (tensorflow seed)
seed = 3                                          # to keep results consistent (numpy seed)
(m, n_H0, n_W0, n_C0) = X_train.shape             
n_y = Y_train.shape[1]                            
costs = []                                        # To keep track of the cost

# Create Placeholders of the correct shape
### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
X, Y = create_placeholders(n_H0, n_W0, n_C0, n_y)
### END CODE HERE ###

# Initialize parameters
### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
parameters = initialize_parameters()
### END CODE HERE ###

# Forward propagation: Build the forward propagation in the tensorflow graph
### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
Z3 = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
### END CODE HERE ###

# Cost function: Add cost function to tensorflow graph
### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
cost = compute_cost(Z3, Y)
### END CODE HERE ###

# Backpropagation: Define the tensorflow optimizer. Use an AdamOptimizer that minimizes the cost.
### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
optimizer =tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
### END CODE HERE ###

# Initialize all the variables globally
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start the session to compute the tensorflow graph
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initialization
    sess.run(init)

    # Do the training loop
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        minibatch_cost = 0.
        num_minibatches = int(m / minibatch_size) # number of minibatches of size minibatch_size in the train set
        seed = seed + 1
        minibatches = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, minibatch_size, seed)

        for minibatch in minibatches:

            # Select a minibatch
            (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch
            # IMPORTANT: The line that runs the graph on a minibatch.
            # Run the session to execute the optimizer and the cost, the feedict should contain a minibatch for (X,Y).
            ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
            _ , temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer , cost] , feed_dict= {X:minibatch_X , Y : minibatch_Y })
            ### END CODE HERE ###

            minibatch_cost += temp_cost / num_minibatches


        # Print the cost every epoch
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:
            print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, minibatch_cost))
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 1 == 0:
            costs.append(minibatch_cost)


    # plot the cost
    plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
    plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
    plt.show()

    # Calculate the correct predictions
    predict_op = tf.argmax(Z3, 1)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(predict_op, tf.argmax(Y, 1))

    # Calculate accuracy on the test set
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print(accuracy)
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
    test_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test})
    print("Train Accuracy:", train_accuracy)
    print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy)

    return train_accuracy, test_accuracy, parameters
```

In the line

```
 temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer , cost] , feed_dict= {X:minibatch_X , Y : minibatch_Y })
        ### END CODE HERE ###
```

Why do I run two variables optimizer and cost ...shouldn't just running optimizer
 be enough as optimizer is even more furtehr in computation graph . Am a beginner in TensorFlow so maybe am asking something very beginner level ..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
optimizer =tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

is used to update your weights, and

```
cost = compute_cost(Z3, Y)
```

is used just to calculate current cost, so if you evaluate just `cost` without `optimizer`, you wont't have any progress in learning, just recieve your current (initial in your case) cost.

Comment: I  have edited the question sorry for that ..I wanted to ask if I can only run the optimizer

Answer (score 1):

Only `optimizer` is need for training. But people normally use `cost` or `loss` to track the performance of the model on the training data. But in principal only `optimizer` is enough.